# render two or more icons inside column of reactable in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to add two or more icons inside a reactable column.

```
<Td column="conf" className="col-md-1">
    <span className="fa fa-trash"></span>
    <span className="fa fa-pencil"></span> // only work with one
</Td>
```

if i try to render with only one icon this work fine, but when i try to render more than one icon the rendered input is [object Object],[object Object] and not the icons spected.

How can i fix it?

some ideas?

---

I try creating a specific component with only the icon and still not working for more than one icon.

```
<Td column="conf" className="col-md-1">
  <IconTrashButton />
  <IconPencilButton /> //Only work with one component
</Td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem appears to be with whatever `<Td>` is (package/custom component) - it should just be rendering `this.props.children` but that doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: Have you getting any error on console ?

Comment: @KushalJain No, sadly there is not exist any error on console

Comment: I can solve this issue. Based on the comments, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how to solve this issue basen on the comments.

The `<Td>` element only render one `this.props.children`. So when he have more than one children, the render fail. and the output is some like `[object Object],[object Object]`.

So, the final code look like this

```
<Td column="conf" className="col-md-1">
 <div>
  <IconTrashButton />
  <IconPencilButton />
 </div>
</Td>
```

I hope this help someone else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put each in a separate block icon scan or a div

```
<Td column="conf" className="col-md-1">
    <span><span className="fa fa-trash"></span></span>
    <div><span className="fa fa-pencil"></span></div> // only work with one
</Td>
```

Comment: I find how to solve the issue! i let the final code in another answer. Thanks.